# What is this plant with flowers that resemble butterflies?

Tags: identification

[image]

Living in Toowoomba Queensland Australia, trying to identify this plant.

Answer (score 7):

*Gaura lindheimeri* (or *Oenothera lindheimeri*). The taxonomy seems somewhat unclear; The Plant List gives *Gaura lindheimeri* as the accepted name and *Oenothera lindheimeri* as a synonym, whereas many other sources refer to *Oenothera* as the current name and *Gaura* as a synonym or "old/ previous" name.

http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/kew-2818180

It is a popular garden plant and there are many named cultivars sold and cultivated, however it looks like it is becoming naturalised in many parts of Australia with the potential to become an environmental weed.

The links below contain images and info:

https://keyserver.lucidcentral.org/weeds/data/media/Html/oenothera_lindheimeri.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaura_lindheimeri